# How do I web-scrape a JSP with Python, Selenium and BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm an absolute beginner experimenting web-scraping with Python.
I'm trying to extract the location of ATMs from this URL:

`https://www.visa.com/atmlocator/mobile/index.jsp#(page:results,params:(query:'Tokyo,%20Japan'))`

using the following code.

```
#Script to scrape locations and addresses from VISA's ATM locator


# import the necessary libraries (to be installed if not available):

from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


#ChromeDriver
#(see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started as reference)

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/DefaultUser/Local Settings/Application Data/Google/Chrome/Application/chromedriver.exe")

offices=[] #List to branches/ATM names
addresses=[] #List to branches/ATM locations
driver.get("https://www.visa.com/atmlocator/mobile/index.jsp#(page:results,params:(query:'Tokyo,%20Japan'))") 


content = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, features = "lxml")


#the following code extracts all the content inside the tags displaying the information requested

for a in soup.findAll('li',attrs={'class':'visaATMResultListItem'}): 
    name=a.find('li', attrs={'class':'data-label'}) 
    address=a.find('li', attrs={'class':'data-label'}) 
    offices.append(name.text)
    addresses.append(address.text)


#next row defines the dataframe with the results of the extraction

df = pd.DataFrame({'Office':offices,'Address':addresses})


#next row displays dataframe content

print(df)


#export data to .CSV file named 'branches.csv'
with open('branches.csv', 'a') as f:
    df.to_csv(f, header=True)
```

The script seems to work correctly, at first, since Chromedriver starts and shows the results as required in the browser, but no result is returned:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Office, Address]
Index: []
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Maybe I made a mistake in choosing the selectors?

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.get("https://www.visa.com/atmlocator/mobile/index.jsp#(page:results,params:(query:'Tokyo,%20JAPAN'))")
time.sleep(2)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

na = []
addr = []
for name in soup.findAll("a", {'class': 'visaATMPlaceLink'}):
    na.append(name.text)
for add in soup.findAll("p", {'class': 'visaATMAddress'}):
    addr.append(add.get_text(strip=True, separator=" "))

with open('out.csv', 'w', newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['Name', 'Address'])
    for _na, _addr in zip(na, addr):
        writer.writerow([_na, _addr])

driver.quit()
```

Output: [Click-Here](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/a6de25fbd228b2dacc9f7b3d8bf6e2cc/out.csv)

Comment: this worked for me, after replacing

`driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)`
with `webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="C:/Users/DefaultUser/AppData/geckodriver.exe")`
and placing the geckodriver in that folder.

Thanks a lot

Comment: @Edo seems that's means you were not including geckodriver in `Python` folder. or you installed it as `user`

Comment: accepted and upvoted (but "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score".)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the locators, use

```
for a in soup.findAll('li',attrs={'class':'visaATMResultListItem'}): 
    name = a.find('p', attrs={'class':'visaATMPlaceName '}) 
    address = a.find('p', attrs={'class':'visaATMAddress'}) 
    offices.append(name.text)
    addresses.append(address.text)
```

Comment: I tried this but still:

`Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Office, Address]
Index: []

Process finished with exit code 0`