# I am wanting to pull some data about mortgages from the web

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

For example, take a look at this page. https://erecord.co.lubbock.tx.us/recorder/eagleweb/viewDoc.jsp?node=DOCCL-OPR19830027670 
I would like to get all the data from a page like that with the user entering a name to my program.
Should I do this with web scraping or is using an API (if there is one) best? How would you go about tackling this project?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is definitely API first if one exists. The second is to figure out what type of pages the site is serving. It looks like JSP, so any of the JSP related scraping would be the way forward. Not sure it merits another answer since there's lots of stuff out there.

For example here are answers to scraping jsp with python:

[How do I web-scrape a JSP with Python, Selenium and BeautifulSoup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59624831/how-do-i-web-scrape-a-jsp-with-python-selenium-and-beautifulsoup)